# What is meant by Account is disabled in dba_users password column for account status as locked?

Tags: oracle-11g-r2

When querying dba_views, for some of the users the password column shows account disabled. These users are locked accounts as account_status column says. I want to understand what is meant by account disabled? Is it same as expired and locked account or it has some other meaning?

Comment: Which Oracle account you are querying the 'dba_views'.Because Oracle comes with a few default accounts that should never be locked or dropped. These include: SYS, SYSTEM, SYSMAN (it comes from Oracle 10g).

Comment: There is no such thing as an account status of "disabled". Accounts are either open, expired, locked or "expired & locked". Where are you seeing a status of "disabled"?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to understand what is meant by account disabled? Is it same as expired and locked account or it has some other meaning?

As per Oracle BOL , **Yes**, A locked account is an account for which login is disabled.

**For Example** : Oracle Database provides sample schema account, SCOTT. The SCOTT schema contains the tables EMP, DEPT, SALGRADE, and BONUS. The SCOTT account is used in examples throughout the Oracle Database documentation set. When you install Oracle Database, the SCOTT account is locked and expired.

> Locking an account preserves the user password, as well as other
>   account information, but makes the account unavailable to anyone who
>   tries to log in to the database using that account. Unlocking it makes
>   the account available again.

For your Ref:-  [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10897/users_secure.htm#ADMQS12001) and [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28337/tdpsg_user_accounts.htm)